# Continuous integration Xcode Server after trigger $XCS_PRODUCT not set

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, bots, xcode-server

I had a bot that was working perfectly under Xcode 6.4. An after trigger script was automatically uploading the IPA using this path : "$XCS_OUTPUT_DIR/$XCS_PRODUCT"

However (even after redoing a bot from scratch) it appears that :

- $XCS_PRODUCT is Always empty.
- $XCS_OUTPUT_DIR is pointing to a folder that does not exist because after checking out on server it appears that Xcode server is storing .ipa there : /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/IntegrationAssets/

How to find my .ipa without this variable during my after trigger script?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. The IPA isn't produced until my script stopped looking for it...

Comment: I sent a bug report at Apple, someone marked it as a duplicate, let's hope this got fixed soon! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and after discussion on [Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/19066)
I found out that there actually is .IPA file inside

```
/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/Integration-INTEGRATION_ID/ExportedProduct/
```

directory and you can access it from **After Trigger Script** by using something like

```
originalBinaryName=$(basename "${XCS_ARCHIVE%.*}".ipa)
originalBinaryPath="${XCS_OUTPUT_DIR}/ExportedProduct/Apps/${originalBinaryName}"
```

I have also sent a bug report, because **$XCS_PRODUCT** should not be empty anyway, and it would be nice to have new environment variable for the complete path of **.IPA** file.

Comment: I tried something similar, but it appears that all .ipa are generated after completion of "after trigger script". Have you tried your solution? Is it working?

Comment: Yup, it's working now. IPA's are there when 'after trigger' is executed.

Comment: You can also check existance of files in terminal while integration is going on. Maybe you had wrong path to file or something.

Comment: My XCS_OUTPUT_DIR did not exist when I was trying it. So I tried with IntegrationAssets/ which wasn't generated. i will try ur solution! Thank!

Comment: You're right about IntegrationAssets directory, it's created only after the integration is finished, so you'll have to see what's going on with your XCS_OUTPUT_DIR variable, mine was ok and this is how I got the IPA file name: by using XCS_ARCHIVE last path component and replacing extension (`originalBinaryName` in the example).

Comment: Excellent this works! Perfect work around before having official FIX