# Xcode Bot: how to get .ipa path on a post trigger script?

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, bots, xcode-bots

I'm using a bot to archive an iOS app, and I need to get the .ipa product path in order to publish it into our distribution system.

Bot settings:

[image]

And using a script to print all env variables, non of them contains a path to the ipa file. In addition, some of the variables are pointed to directory that does not exist, i.e: `XCS_OUTPUT_DIR`

Here the env variable output:

```
XCS=1
XCS_ANALYZER_WARNING_CHANGE=-31
XCS_ANALYZER_WARNING_COUNT=0
XCS_ARCHIVE=/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/Integration-771867708dfac45bba10a1998c118912/MyApp.xcarchive
XCS_BOT_ID=771867708dfac45bba10a1998c007d43
XCS_BOT_NAME='MyApp Distribution'
XCS_BOT_TINY_ID=DBB85BD
XCS_DERIVED_DATA_DIR=/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/Caches/771867708dfac45bba10a1998c007d43/DerivedData
XCS_ERROR_CHANGE=-1
XCS_ERROR_COUNT=0
XCS_INTEGRATION_ID=771867708dfac45bba10a1998c118912
XCS_INTEGRATION_NUMBER=19
XCS_INTEGRATION_RESULT=warnings
XCS_INTEGRATION_TINY_ID=F7D4469
XCS_OUTPUT_DIR=/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/Integration-771867708dfac45bba10a1998c118912
XCS_SOURCE_DIR=/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/Caches/771867708dfac45bba10a1998c007d43/Source
XCS_TESTS_CHANGE=0
XCS_TESTS_COUNT=0
XCS_TEST_FAILURE_CHANGE=0
XCS_TEST_FAILURE_COUNT=0
XCS_WARNING_CHANGE=0
XCS_WARNING_COUNT=26
XCS_XCODEBUILD_LOG=/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/Integration-771867708dfac45bba10a1998c118912/xcodebuild.log
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=com.apple.xcsbuildd
```

In addition to that, I was able to confirm that `.ipa` files are being created in another folder (`<path to server>/IntegrationAssets/<integration id>/<integration number>/`), but that path is not accessible from an env variable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Well, after a lot of research and testing and all, apparently there is something wrong with bots in the latest Xcode (7.2) + Server version (5.0.15) not loading the correct environment variables.

My current solution was to create the path manually based on existing env variables:

```
ARCHIVE_PATH="${XCS_ARCHIVE}"
ARCHIVE_NAME="${ARCHIVE_PATH##*/}"
IPA_NAME="${ARCHIVE_NAME%.*}.ipa"
IPA_PATH="${XCS_OUTPUT_DIR}/ExportedProduct/Apps/${IPA_NAME}"
```

Which I did based on:
[Continuous integration Xcode Server after trigger $XCS_PRODUCT not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32699179/continuous-integration-xcode-server-after-trigger-xcs-product-not-set)

Answer (score 1):

Just a small update--In Xcode 9.4.1 at least $XCS_PRODUCT is set correctly, so you can just use that, e. g. for HockeyApp:

```
curl -F "status=2" -F "notify=1" -F "ipa=@${XCS_PRODUCT}" -H "X-HockeyAppToken: <token>" https://rink.hockeyapp.net/api/2/apps/upload
```