# Xcode 9 bot integration ipa missing at XCS_PRODUCT path

Tags: ios, bots, xcode-server, xcode9.3

I am working on Continuous Integration with Xcode 9. I have successfully setup Server & Bot.

Integration works fine.

**Requirement:**
I required ipa path in Post Script to upload on my server.

**Problem:**
I am using **`XCS_PRODUCT`** variable for fetching ipa path.

Here is **`ENV`** Output from post trigger:

```
XCS_BOT_NAME=TestXCTest Bot
XCS=1
XCS_WARNING_CHANGE=0
XCS_SOURCE_DIR=/Users/xcodeserver/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder/Bots/b2642ba61e9ffe8554a9d17d1f0126d5/Source
SHELL=/bin/bash
XCS_INTEGRATION_RESULT=succeeded
TMPDIR=/var/folders/wv/33mqmjhn525clw9zzx2c0xq80000gs/T/
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.xHus0eJhWj/Render
XCS_TEST_FAILURE_COUNT=0
XCS_INTEGRATION_ID=51c2cf4d7b95c0c4a4f948f23001620e
XCS_BOT_TINY_ID=B705E6C
USER=xcodeserver
XCS_ARCHIVE=/Users/xcodeserver/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder/Integration-51c2cf4d7b95c0c4a4f948f23001620e/TestXCTest.xcarchive
XCS_TEST_FAILURE_CHANGE=0
XCS_INTEGRATION_TINY_ID=2C6684E
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.W6OUJYNErV/Listeners
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F9:0:0
XCS_PRIMARY_REPO_DIR=/Users/xcodeserver/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder/Bots/b2642ba61e9ffe8554a9d17d1f0126d5/Source/TestXCTest
PATH=/Applications/Xcode_9.3.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
XCS_BOT_ID=b2642ba61e9ffe8554a9d17d1f0126d5
PWD=/Users/xcodeserver/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder/Bots/b2642ba61e9ffe8554a9d17d1f0126d5/Source
XCS_XCODEBUILD_LOG=/Users/xcodeserver/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder/Integration-51c2cf4d7b95c0c4a4f948f23001620e/xcodebuild.log
XCS_PRODUCT=/Users/xcodeserver/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder/Integration-51c2cf4d7b95c0c4a4f948f23001620e/ExportedProduct/TestXCTest.ipa
XCS_PRIMARY_REPO_BRANCH=master
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
XCS_ERROR_COUNT=0
XCS_ANALYZER_WARNING_COUNT=0
XCS_TESTS_CHANGE=-2
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
XCS_ERROR_CHANGE=0
SHLVL=1
HOME=/Users/xcodeserver
XCS_DERIVED_DATA_DIR=/Users/xcodeserver/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder/Bots/b2642ba61e9ffe8554a9d17d1f0126d5/DerivedData
XCS_ANALYZER_WARNING_CHANGE=0
LOGNAME=xcodeserver
XCS_WARNING_COUNT=0
XCS_TESTS_COUNT=0
XCS_OUTPUT_DIR=/Users/xcodeserver/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder/Integration-51c2cf4d7b95c0c4a4f948f23001620e
XCS_INTEGRATION_NUMBER=13
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Here it show ipa at this path:

> /Users/xcodeserver/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder/Integration-51c2cf4d7b95c0c4a4f948f23001620e/ExportedProduct/TestXCTest.ipa

But In finder There isn't any folder like **Integration-....**.
[image]

**So Question is How can I get ipa path?**

I have checked many questions regarding this like:

[Continuous integration Xcode Server after trigger $XCS_PRODUCT not set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32699179/1597744)

[Xcode Bot: how to get .ipa path on a post trigger script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35605608/1597744)

but didn't get answer for Xcode 9.

Comment: According to the https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/EnvironmentVariableReference.html XCS_PRODUCT has meaning "if a product was exported from an archive during the integration"

Comment: @AlexanderUshakov: Yes I'm exporting ipa during the integration/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found issue**

> Xcode is deleting Integration folder after completion.

Solution:

I have added below post script to copy ipa:

```
rm -r "/Users/xcodeserver/Desktop/ipa/*"
cp -R "${XCS_OUTPUT_DIR}/ExportedProduct/" "/Users/xcodeserver/Desktop/ipa/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another tip, if $XCS_PRODUCT is empty make sure other triggers prior to this one did not fail. My pod file update script needed to be changed, the downstream upload trigger was still being run but it did not have this env variable set.